# Removing CST branch during visit

Tags: rascal

I have a syntax containing this expression: `{Binding ","}+`

At some points, I would like to remove Binding based on their value. Is there a simple way of doing this inside a visit expression?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use concrete syntax matching, it will be something like the following:

In this case we are removing the last binding:

```
visit (myProgram) {

case (Expression) `let <{Binding ","}+ otherBindings>, <Binding myBinding> in <Expression e>` 
  => (Expression) `let <{Binding ","}+ otherBindings> in <Expression e>`
}
```

You could also remove the first binding:

```
visit (myProgram) {

case (Expression) `let <Binding myBinding>, <{Binding ","}+ otherBindings> in <Expression e>` 
  => (Expression) `let <{Binding ","}+ otherBindings> in <Expression e>`
}
```

I expect the pattern match for myBinding to have more details, or you have a `when` clause or something to decide if and when to remove the binding.

Or one in the middle:

```
visit (myProgram) {

case (Expression) `let <{Binding ","}+ firstThese>, <Binding myBinding>, <{Binding ","}+ thenOthers> in <Expression e>` 
  => (Expression) `let <{Binding ","}+ firstThese>, <{Binding ","}+ theOthers> in <Expression e>`
}
```

Rascal takes care of removing the additional separator commas where necessary.

Note that all the types in the patterns will become optional in the near future, and you'd write:

```
{Binding ","}+ bs1, bs2; 
Binding myBinding;

visit (myProgram) {

case (Expression) `let <bs1>, <myBinding>, <bs2> in <Expression e>` 
  => (Expression) `let <bs1>, <bs2> in <Expression e>`
}
```